# Share and add a custom message?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I've integrated a Facebook share button into my site. The client now wishes to add a prepopulated message when a user presses the share button, so this can be written to the users timeline. (If they agree).

I've checked out the share button on facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

But I cant find anywhere how to add a custom message to the share button?

Comment: That is not allowed according to https://developers.facebook.com/policy so if they don't want their app banned they should not do it

Comment: It's not a facebook app, it's a webpage.

Comment: Ok, it is not possible and if even if it was the webpage would be banned from sharing anything in like a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add facebooks OG tags to the head of your page, Facebook will read these and add the content. You can add a custom title, image and description.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.website.com/thumbnail" />
```

If you need to add a custom title, image or description per page then you'll need to use a php constant to define these on a per-page basis.

With something like:

```
<?php 
$title = 'Title Here';
$desc = 'Description goes here...';
?>
```

Then the meta tags would look like this.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $desc ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.website.com/thumbnail" />
```

Check out the docs here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/webmasters/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), you are not allowed to prefill the message:

> 2.3: Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the
>   person can edit or remove the content before sharing

...and it´s not possible with the Share Plugin anyway. The message must be 100% user generated and there is no possible way to implement this.